# New to Python - Trying to understand where my code is going wrong

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm writing a guessing game to help understand my knowledge of loops (specifically while loops right now). I got the idea from freecodecamp and saw their answer, while I understand what they did. I would like to understand where my code goes wrong.

Currently when I run it I cannot exit the loop by inputting the correct number, only by entering 4 tries.

```
guess_counter = 0
tries = 4
num = 4
while True:
    guess = input("Guess a number: ").isdigit()
    guess_counter += 1
    if guess == num:
        print(f'You win!')
        break
    if guess_counter == tries:
        print(f'YOU LOSE!')
```

Comment: isdigit return boolean (true if string is a digit.

Answer (score 4):

Python's [`isdigit`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isdigit.asp) returns a Boolean, a `True` or `False` value. So your code is checking:

```
if True == 4
```

or

```
if False == 4
```

This will always result in `False`, so you can never win.
If you want to only allow integers, you can use `int()`:

```
guess_counter = 0
tries = 4
num = 4
while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
    guess_counter += 1
    if guess == num:
        print(f'You win!')
        break
    if guess_counter == tries:
        print(f'YOU LOSE!')
```

Output:

```
Guess a number: 5
Guess a number: 4
You win!
```

Comment: Thank you! That explains perfectly.

Comment: @conrito345 No problem. If my post answered your question, consider clicking the check mark to accept it as the answer.